# ORA-00922 encountered in Oracle 11gR2 installer

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, installation

I've just run the installer for Oracle 11gR2 on a Windows Server 2008 (64-bit) OS.

I encountered the "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option" error at the last stage of installation when it was doing something like "cloning the database". I ignored the error and then immediately got a "ORA-28000: the account is locked" error. The installer then completed successfully.

I looked in the logs for the installation ("C:\app\administrator\cfgtoollogs\dbca\orcl") and found one file named "postScripts.log" which contains these two error messages. Here is the contents of that file:

```
     1
     1
alter user CTXSYS account unlock identified by ******
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option


ERROR:
ORA-28000: the account is locked


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
dropping default lexer preference...
SP2-0640: Not connected
dropping default wordlist preference...
SP2-0640: Not connected
dropping default stoplist preference...
SP2-0640: Not connected
dropping default policy...
SP2-0640: Not connected
SP2-0640: Not connected
Enter value for lang_abbr: SP2-0310: unable to open file "C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\ctx\admin\defaults\drdefset.sql"
```

Has anyone else encountered this error before, or know how to resolve it? Will the database function correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution on my own!

It seems that there is a bug in the Oracle installer - it doesn't like it if you start your system password with a number.

I completely uninstalled Oracle using the deinstall utility and then reinstalled Oracle, this time specifying a system password beginning with a letter. This solved the problem!

I hope this helps anyone else encountering this annoying issue.

Additionally, user HanFromBs found that the installer doesn't like special characters (- or +) at the start or end of the password, so watch out for this too.

Comment: additional Info:
the installer doesnt like special characters (- or +) at the start or end of the password.
It gave me the same error as numbers at the start of the password

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm sure that these requirements for passwords are not anywhere in the Oracle documentation, which isn't very helpful!

Comment: Can you edit that info into the answer? It's better there than in the comments and it looks like useful info.

Comment: Can confirm that this works. Had the same problem, I.E., used `deinstall` on the Oracle software, reinstalled and created a new instance. Got the above mentioned error, changed system password to something with a letter as the first character and it worked.